# Appliction software updater has closed unexpectedly

Tags: package-management, update-manager, cache

[Error in opening the cache, How can i fix this issue getting this from long time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2QRq.jpg)

[application updater closed unexpectedly, when clicking on updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlTNT.png)
Please Help!, not able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Use commands in terminal when everything else (GUI tools) fails.

Start by running `sudo apt update` and take note of any error messages as some require corrective user actions.

Proceed with `sudo apt full-upgrade` in order to fully update your system.